The fast.log in suricata has no redis related content
My Set：
kali：redis client
Ubuntu：redis server、suricata
Customized rules are placed in /var/lib/suricata/rules redis.rules
I'm testing if suricata can monitor redis related traffic, configured redis client on kali VM (127.16.232.129), redis server on Ubuntu (172.16.232.128) VM, suricata is built on Ubuntu and listening port is At the end of the test, there is no redis-related content in the fast.log in suricata.
There may be three reasons for my analysis:
1, whether suricata can listen to the traffic between redis client and server
2, whether the rules of suricata are configured correctly
3、Monitoring redis rules are correct or not
After experimental testing, is to monitor redis custom rules are not correct, the following is my custom rules：
alert tcp any any -> any 6379 (msg:"Redis SET Command Detected"; content:"*3\\r\\n$3\\r\\nSET\\r\\n"; nocase; flow:to_server; sid:1000004; rev:2;)
alert tcp any any -> any 6379 (msg:"Redis GET Command Detected"; content:"*2\\r\\n$3\\r\\nGET\\r\\n"; nocase; flow:to_server; sid:1000005; rev:2;)
alert tcp any any -> any 6379 (msg:"Redis PUBLISH Command Detected"; content:"*3\\r\\n$7\\r\\nPUBLISH\\r\\n"; nocase; flow:to_server; sid:1000006; rev:1;)
alert tcp any any -> any 6379 (msg:"Redis SUBSCRIBE Command Detected"; content:"*2\\r\\n$9\\r\\nSUBSCRIBE\\r\\n"; nocase; flow:to_server; sid:1000007; rev:1;)
alert tcp any any -> any 6379 (msg:"Redis LPUSH Command Detected"; content:"*3\\r\\n$5\\r\\nLPUSH\\r\\n"; nocase; flow:to_server; sid:1000008; rev:1;)

When I change the content to *, fast.log will appear related content.
alert tcp any any -> any 6379 (msg:"Detected Redis traffic"; flow:to_server,established; content:"*"; depth:1; sid:1000009; rev:1;)

so it is my custom rules in the content of the problem, but I do not know what is wrong with this writing, perhaps I am not too familiar with the suricata rule format, can anyone tell me where the problem or how I should change the rules!
